# Webpy displaying pyc file path instead of print statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py, web-frameworks

I'm sure I've missed something really obvious in the tutorials, but trying to learn webpy framework by implementing a simple script and html page.

Here's the main script that I run from the command line to start the "server" (*I don't have the POST function in the Index class working/setup yet properly, but just trying to have the GET function working properly to start with*):

```
import web
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/seanjarp/PythonLearnings/projects/GAME/ChipChippersonGame') 
from ChipChippersonGame import ChipChippersonGame

urls = (
    '/testhtml', 'Index'
) 

app = web.application(urls, globals())
render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.testhtml(ChipChippersonGame)
       # return render.testhtml()
    #def POST(self):
    #    form = web.input(playerinput="HiChip")
    #    user_response = ChipChippersonGame.next_scene(form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This script above is importing another script in a another director, which currently I've reduced to only having a print statement to keep things simple (the import is working properly):

```
print "ChipChippersonGame script is being called"
```

The `testhtml` file looks like this:

```
$def with (ChipChippersonGame)

<html>
    <head>
        <title>What's Up!</title>
    </head>
<body>

$if ChipChippersonGame:
    $ChipChippersonGame

$else:
   <em>Script is not being called!</>

</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, when I load for example this into my browser:

```
http://0.0.0.0:4141/testhtml
```

It prints the following to the browser:

```
<module 'ChipChippersonGame.ChipChippersonGame' from '/Users/seanjarp/PythonLearnings/projects/GAME/ChipChippersonGame/ChipChippersonGame`/ChipChippersonGame.pyc
```

What am I doing incorrectly that's preventing the print statement in the `ChipChippersonGame.py` script from printing to the browser?

I'm assuming I've screwed up how I'm calling or setting up the function in the the `testhtml.html` file.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial module import has a side effect of printing to stdout so it is probably being written to a log when you start up your app.

Second, you are passing a `module` object to your template and then outputting it directly in your markup which is why it is printing out the `__repr__` of the module.

```
$if ChipChippersonGame:
    $ChipChippersonGame
    ^__________________this is a module object hence <module 'ChipChippersonGame.ChipChippersonGame' from
```

Comment: Ok, so just because there's a print statement in a script I'm importing, and even though I'm trying to call or use that function in the html code, it's not setup up to output the print statement to the actual html page?

Comment: Correct. It is referred to as an [import side-effect](http://chrismorgan.info/blog/say-no-to-import-side-effects-in-python.html). If you wanted that to show up in your template then you would have to put it in a function and assign the return value of the function to a template variable instead.